# Why all Emacs packages can suddenly become unsigned and obsolete

Tags: emacs, packages

I don't understand the reason of this and how to fix it:

[image: Emacs packages unsigned]

Maybe something bad happened while updating packages.
Not getting any list of new packages, only displaying installed.

How to fix it?

**Edit:** For some reason I still don't understand `package-archives` is reset to `nil` on start (if set it later - it's ok)

Comment: **FIRST:  Back-up your `elpa` directory somewhere else in case you stuck something in there and forgot it was there -- e.g., custom snippets, etc.**  If you have not invested time modifying the sources and if you have a list of the packages (or a memory) of what packages you want to install, then you could delete the `elpa` directory and start again.  Restart Emacs before adding packages once you have removed the `elpa` directory.

Comment: Thanks, I did it. Then I wanted to rescue my `elpa` folder, set manually `package-archives` var and repeated updating process. That helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was in updating packages:

- something bad happened while updating
- `package-archives` was reset to `nil` on start

One can set manually `package-archives` variable and repeat updating packages process.

So I had this in config:

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu"       . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ;;("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa"     . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
```

But I still needed to execute this code manually after starting Emacs. After updating everything was back to normal state.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. I am having he same exact problem. What was the specific Elisp command that you run to solve the problem ? (e.g. what did you set `package-archives` to?)

Comment: See updated answer